# When I use c9.io ,How can I connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cloud9-ide

c9.io is a verygood website

I have a php zoon , and when I want to connect to MySQL,I don't know password.
I have try [space] root ... 
but,all is wrong.

I can open mysql in shell , no password ,my operate return error:
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'

It's looks like, mysqld is not started 。（I have try “mysqld start”，but faild）

What I want to know, 
Is Mysql service free on c9.io ?

Comment: virtual machines which supports PHP.

Answer (score 6):

We are extremely happy to announce our first iteration of MySQL support in Cloud9. It makes it super easy to install, start and stop a MySQL instance right in your workspace. The nice thing is that every workspace will run a separate database so your projects will never interfere with each other. You can control MySQL with the mysql-ctl command line tool run from the terminal.

```
# start MySQL. Will create an empty database on first start
$ mysql-ctl start

# stop MySQL
$ mysql-ctl stop

# run the MySQL interactive shell
$ mysql-ctl cli
```

> You can then connect to the database with following parameters:
>
> ```
> Option    Value   Comment
> Hostname  $IP The same local IP as the application you run on Cloud9
> Port  3306    The default MySQL port number
> User  $C9_USER    Your Cloud9 user name
> Password  -   No password since you can only access the DB from within the workspace
> Database  c9  The database name
> ```

Of course this is just the beginning. We have for example plans to add a management UI to start and stop databases or pre-installing tools like phpMyAdmin. However we don’t want to make you wait for the fully integrated feature while we already have something that is enabling a lot of use cases and still super easy to use.

Stay tuned and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The  [documentation](https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html) show how start, stop, and run the mysql environment.

Start the MySQL shell `mysql-ctl start` then in yor file.php:

```
$ip =  getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$port = "3306";
$user = "YorUsername";
$DB = "c9";

$conn = mysql_connect('$ip', '$user', '', '$db', '$port')or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('$db','$conn')or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("select * from YourTableName",'$conn')or die(mysql_error());
```

The line `getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")` return the same local IP as the application you run on Cloud9.