# c9.io php pdo connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, pdo, cloud9-ide

I am attempting to connect to a mysql database using the c9.io development environment.  I have followed their [documentation](https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html) and have seen multiple links, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531822/php-connect-to-mysql-db-in-cloud-9), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460519/cloud-9-ide-cant-connect-to-database) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361376/when-i-use-c9-io-how-can-i-connect-to-mysql).

I verified the mysql service is running.  I also verified the PDO extension was installed via phpinfo().  Here is my current code:

```
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$port = '3306';
$user = "username";
$db = "c9";

    try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$ip;port=$port;dbname=$db;charset=utf8",$user,"");
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I get the error `Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.240.x.x' (111)`

If i try localhost as host, I get the error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I also followed a comment from the second link above: `echo $IP` in the terminal which returns 0.0.0.0

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: please explain the downvote.

Comment: Where is your password?

Comment: Cloud9 [documentation](https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html) says "No password since you can only access the DB from within the workspace"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. On https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html it says use $IP for host. You can use getenv("IP") instead or use its value: 0.0.0.0. That should work. 
Please try something like:

```
$dbname = 'c9';
$ip = getenv('IP');
$user = getenv('C9_USER');

mysql_connect($ip, $user, '') or die('Could not connect to mysql');
```